# hiding portion of excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

In my sheet I have some data and I want to use that sheet at different places and I want only some selected portion of that sheet visible and rest of the sheet content will be hidden.

what i am doing is,copying a template file,creating new sheet and data is getting written to this new sheet .Now as this sheet is copied from template,whole data of template will be there is new sheet,that i dont want. That why i want to hide the specific selected data from new sheet.

Any help how to do it?

Comment: Don't understand this at all ... what do you mean "use that sheet at different places"?

Comment: it means that two or more sheets will be using that sheet for data by copying that file. As simple as that.

Comment: @Neha: What programming language are you using to copy a template file and creating a new excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the rows/columns that you don't want to be seen and then use [sheet protection](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-HA010096837.aspx) to keep it hidden. Here's how to do [sheet protection in VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840611.aspx).

Comment: But what i am doing is,copying a template file,creating new sheet and data is getting written to this new sheet .Now as this sheet is copied from template,whole data of template will be there is new sheet,that i dont want. That why i want to hide the specific selected data from new sheet.Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why, if you're using a template, you copy all of the data to begin with.  If you are creating a bunch of different reports then you might consider creating a template for each report and only copying over the data that you need for each specific report.

As for your original question, if you want to delete entire columns or entire rows of information then the following might be useful:

```
'To delete columns
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

'To delete rows
Rows("7:7").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I use templates, but I create a specific template for each type of report because they're all formatted differently.  With the above, I would think that you could include the delete lines in your macro after the "copy" line but before your macro starts copying the actual data to the new sheet.